# What's the date format in php of this date

Tags: php, date-format

What's the date-format in php of the date like **01:29:51 Dec 23, 2013**.
I know this is a very simple question,but i couldn't find out in google.
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Here you go http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php `echo date('H:i:s Md, Y');`

Answer (score 4):

Format is probably **`H:i:s M j, Y`**

<kbd>[**see more here**](http://php.net/date)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$format = date('H:i:s M d, Y');
```

Comment: I strongly disagree with the edit that was made. You can't assume it's going to be used for output directly, nor was that the question. Changed it back @AmalMurali

Comment: Ah, it was an edit. I thought it was originally present in your answer -- hence my comment. Just a note: you can use the `rollback` button in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20814822/revisions), too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo date("H:i:s M d,Y",time());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
 <?php
 echo date('h:i:s M d, Y');
 ?>
```